# Monitoring windows variables using SNMP java manager

Tags: java, snmp

I need to monitor information about certain IPs in my network. This information will be: the devices' names, their locations, the bandwidth on each port and network performance metrics. I have created the SNMP manager using Java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.snmp4j.CommunityTarget;
import org.snmp4j.PDU;
import org.snmp4j.Snmp;
import org.snmp4j.Target;
import org.snmp4j.TransportMapping;
import org.snmp4j.event.ResponseEvent;
import org.snmp4j.mp.SnmpConstants;
import org.snmp4j.smi.Address;
import org.snmp4j.smi.GenericAddress;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OID;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OctetString;
import org.snmp4j.smi.VariableBinding;
import org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping;

public class SNMPManager {

    Snmp snmp = null;
    String Agent = "udp:localhost/161";
    String Oid="1.3.6.1.4.1.9600.1.22.8.5.1.5.";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SNMPManager client = new SNMPManager();
        client.start();
        int counter=0;
        //while(true){
        try{
        String ODIValue = client.getAsString(new OID(client.Oid));//Decrypt the OID
        System.out.println("OID is "+ client.Oid);
        System.out.println("ODIValue is "+ODIValue);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error "+ counter++);
        }
        //}
    }

    private void start() throws IOException {
        TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        snmp = new Snmp(transport);
        transport.listen();
    }


    public String getAsString(OID oid) throws IOException {
        ResponseEvent event = get(new OID[] { oid });//Get IOD from agent
        return event.getResponse().get(0).getVariable().toString(); //Should respond with the OID
    }

    public ResponseEvent get(OID oids[]) throws IOException {
        PDU pdu = new PDU();
        for (OID oid : oids) {
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(oid));
        }
        pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
        ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, getTarget(), null);
        if(event != null) {
            return event;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Time out occured");
    }

    private Target getTarget() {
        Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse(Agent);
        CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
        target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
        target.setAddress(targetAddress);
        target.setRetries(2);
        target.setTimeout(1500);
        target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
        return target;
    }

}
```

I am using the port 161 for SNMP and the localhost for my computer. I have also enabled the SNMP feature on my windows 10. Now I am expecting to get the operating system version but nothing appears. Where is the problem?

And I also need to know where to find the MIBs file on my windows to know all the codes for the system variables.

Comment: Windows SNMP service only implements its own objects defined in these MIB documents, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/snmp/the-snmp-management-information-base-mib- So when you try to access invalid objects, you won't get anything.

Comment: The file contains only the mibs data but no OIDs to be able to retrieve the data.

Comment: You misunderstood the SNMP concepts. Loading MIB documents at manager side is useless. It is the vendor of the SNMP agent who determines which objects are implemented, and only the objects defined in Microsoft MIB documents are valid. Anything under `1.3.6.1.4.1.9600.1.22.8.5.1.5` is not supported by Microsoft.

Comment: So should I search for MIBs or OIDs to get the values of certain variables like a system version number for example?

Comment: That Microsoft article mentioned where to find Microsoft MIB documents. You can check which objects are there, and if there is one for your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on a project with similar requirements where we used to monitor data of remote IPs. You can take a look at the source code here
[github.com/ashish2199/Nework_Bandwidth_Monitor](https://github.com/ashish2199/Nework_Bandwidth_Monitor)